# Ruby Savon SOAP client can't find requested URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, ruby-on-rails-5, savon

I am using the Savon Gem in my Rails 5 app.
Everything was working fine and suddenly I get an error:

```
The requested URL /soap/IHubInterfaces was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.URL.com Port 443
```

I have a GUI tool called SoapUI and with this tool everything works. Like I mentioned my Rails app also worked until 2 weeks ago.

Any ideas how I can start debugging?

Comment: Does this error occur for wsdl host or namespaces host? Try to request this URL using `curl` or request it in your browser. Also, it could be helpful to add `log_level: :debug` when you initialize Savon client.

Comment: adding log_level does not give me any further information